# How to make Android 12 let me pick the app every time when opening URLs on a particular domain?

Tags: applications, hyperlinks

If I click a Youtube link, which opens another app, I want to choose every single time which app to use. This worked fine in Android 11, since I could just set the option to 'ask every time' in the app manager, or something like that, and never tap 'always use this app'. However, this was rehashed in Android 12, at least on Pixels, such that I can only enable or disable opening certain links in a particular app. Is there a way to revert to asking always, if just for a certain domain?

If I turn on opening the links for the official Youtube app, it becomes the default one for Youtube links. If I then also enable the same for the alternative app, the Youtube app still opens by default. There's a nuance that the Youtube app has 'verified links' for the youtube domain, and the alternative app just has a list of domains with '0 verified links'. Does this mean that Google simply took the decision away from the users and gave it to domain owners?

[Google's instructions on the matter](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6271667?hl=en) is that I need to turn off automatically opening links, for each of the alternative apps. But after that links are just opened in the browser instead of letting me pick the app.

Even weirder is that some links still do ask me to pick an app—but not links to Youtube, which is what I use the most.

This question was previously asked in regard to Android 8—but as mentioned above, the feature worked fine in v11, and then the problem cropped up again in v12.

---

Edit: the docs on [‘Verifying Android app links’](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks) say that only one app can be set as the default for a domain, which is understandable. This implies that enabling opening links in a particular app sets it as the only choice, and the functionality of letting the user pick the app each time is gone in this configuration. (Perhaps with the links that still give me the choice of the apps to use, those apps are built for an older version of the API—I might need to look into that.)

It's also said there:

> Before you manually invoke domain verification on a device, you must reset the state of Android App Links on the test device. To do so, run the following command in a terminal window: `adb shell pm set-app-links --package PACKAGE_NAME 0 all`

> This command puts the device in the same state that it's in before the user chooses default apps for any domains.

It's unclear whether this works on a particular app or all apps on the phone, and what the behavior is when the phone is in this state. Presumably it's back to when opening links is disabled for each of the apps, and they're opened in the browser instead. It's also vaguely and hazily suggested that Android will verify the links again on seeing a url-opening intent, not just after upgrading the app.

Kinda sounds like my only solution is to have a separate app that acts as the default for the links, and have it pop up the choice of the other apps to kick the link to.

Comment: Not sure if this still works, but there is the [BetterOpenWith](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith) app which is set-up as default web browser but instead of loading the web page it shows an app selector and then allows to redirect the URLs to the app you have selected. https://xdaforums.com/t/app-4-0-better-open-with.2831738/

Comment: @Robert Yeah, I've encountered that or another such app, and didn't understand back then why I would need it. Remembered about it while writing the edit for the post. Though since Android allows adding domains to open with an app by default, this probably can work without setting it as the browser. (I think even that Tasker/Automate can serve for this.)